# How does one check if a curve is reducible

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective complex surface. Let $C$ be a curve on $X$. I know that $O_X(C)$ is ample and globally generated. The curve $C$ is locally reducible at $m$ points, that is I know that at these $m$ points, the local equation of the curve looks like $uv=0$ for some choice of local coordinates. Is there some criterion for checking $C$ is globally reducible? I want to write $C$ as $C_1+C_2$ where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are infact smooth isomorphic curves which meet at these $m$ points.

In another direction, how does one check if an ample globally generated linear system on $X$ such as $|O_X(C)|$ has reducible curves?

Answer (score 5):

You can blow up these $m$ points and check whether the strict transform of the curve is connected (by computing global sections of its structure sheaf).

Comment: thank you. Any insights on the second question about existence reducible curves in a linear system?

Comment: I don't think I can say something useful here.